# How do I create a Google Calendar event [file] (ics) to occur on the 4th Friday in September yearly?

Tags: google-calendar

I've tried:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20221028
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20221028
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=4FR
DESCRIPTION:
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:10
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Event on the fourth Friday of October every year.
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

This creates the first one on the 4th Fri in Sept but all the others are the 4th Fri in Jan of every year.

I can do it in the ui but it would easier to code a .ics file.  I'd do this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

While I was posting, I thought to create the event and then export the event to figure out if I could export the event and view the .ics file.  Well, you can't export one event but I did export the calendar and found the event.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20221028
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20221028
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=12;BYDAY=4FR
DESCRIPTION:
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:10
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Event on the fourth Friday of October every year.
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
```

Here is the important part:

```
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=12;BYDAY=4FR
```

Frequency = Monthly
Interval = 12 (months)
BYDAY = 4th Friday

This event will take place every 12 months on the 4th Friday.  Essentially, once a year on the 4th Friday.

```
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20220923T170000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20220924T033000
```

This is when the event will start and end on that 4th Friday (or in this case, start on Fri and end on Sat).

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).